# Setting restrictions on accessing html pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I was wondering if there is a way of only allowing access to an html webpage if it is called form another page.

For example. 
I have a page: hello.php. On this page, there is a button which would redirect you to bye.php.

However, currently, if someone types bye.php in the browser, they can access the page.

How do I make it so that bye.php can only be accessed if the button is pressed on hello.php and NOT by directly entering bye.php into the browser.

Thank you

Comment: PHP sessions would be one way.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your code look at the CGI variable HTTP_REFERER and check that the domain held there is your domain (ie it's a page on your site), and reject the request if not.

It shows the page that was being viewed when the browser was directed towards your page.

[HTTP_Referer wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

Or if you want to be specific you could check it againast a list of pages whcih are allower to link to it.

Note that this isn't a secure feature; it's possible for hackers (who don't use web browsers) to fudge this and get around it, but for your agevrage user it'll work ok.

Comment: Just don't blindly trust the `Referer` header, since it could be overwritten by a malicious user

Comment: you beat me to it - I've just added that in edit to my post :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php):

The script that runs when a user presses the button in question:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($buttonWasPressed){
    //Button was pressed, so create a session variable.
    $_SESSION['button_pressed'] = true;
}
```

Then, at the top of bye.php, you can protect it like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['button_pressed'])){
    //Session variable does not exist - Redirect user back to hello.php
    header('Location: hello.php');
    exit;
}
```